# shows warning that suplied argument is not a valid

Tags: php, mysql

while performing inner join when i add data in mysql it shows a error  mysql_fetch_array is not a valid argument. **code is below:**

```
    echo $sql="SELECT * FROM info
 INNER JOIN item ON info.info_id=item.info_id where item.info_id=".$info_id;
        $query=mysql_query($sql);
         while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        { 
             echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>" .$result['Name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$result['Item']. "</td>";
         echo "<td>" .$result['Price']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$result['info_id']. "</td>";
             echo "<td><a href='item.php?act=edit&id=".$result['id']."'>Edit</a></td>";
             echo "<td><a href='item.php?act=delete&id=".$result['id']."'>Delete</a></td>";
             echo "<td><a href='item.php?act=item&id=".$result['id']."'>Item</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

**while running the above code it shows the following warning:**

warning:mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resourc

Comment: Check your query that returns anything. I think it returns false

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are probably also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Please share the creating connection code, are you selecting the database? One thing important is `mysql` api is deprecated use `mysqli` instead.

Comment: check `echo mysql_num_rows($query);` before ur `fetch` statement

Comment: @suhel - an empty result set wouldn't give that warning

Comment: @Quentin is right, you should probably not be using mysql_query as it is deprecated ([starting from PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php))

Comment: try checking error `$query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())`..I think it should return you with some thing useful..... and I suggest you start using mysqli_* functions

Comment: @Ummar i have created connection with the database, and the connection is successfully established. **mysql_connect('localhost','root','root') or die('oops error in connection');
 mysql_select_db('friend_list') or die('error in selecting db');**

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_query` method probably fails silently. If it does, it returns `FALSE` so you should be doing this:

```
$query=mysql_query($sql);
if (!$query) {
    die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
```